# How can I see the memory view of a DLL residing in a process?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

How can I see the memory view of a DLL residing in a process?

I'm trying to find the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER's e_lfanew by looking at the memory. I can find it in the binary obviously, but I struggle to find it in memory, after a process is running.

The following code should get a path to a dll file and read the binary to a buffer. From there I wanted to identify the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER's e_lfanew. Just wondering how I could actually see this in a memory view representation

```
bool readNtHeader(const char* dllfile)
{

    BYTE* data;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pOldNtHeader;

    std::ifstream File(dllfile, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    auto FileSize = File.tellg();

    data = new BYTE[static_cast<UINT_PTR>(FileSize)];

    File.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    File.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), FileSize);
    File.close();

    std::cout << "pOldNtHeader:" << reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*>(data)->e_lfanew << std::endl;

    pOldNtHeader = reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*>(data + reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*>(data)->e_lfanew);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: [GetModuleHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlew).